# I'd like to add a function on my WP site, to generate the slug using only the first 3 characters of the title. Does anyone know how?

Tags: wordpress, url, slug

In order to create a really simple URL structure, and since the first three characters of my title are numbers and letters, I'd like to put in a function to generate the slug using only first 3 characters of the post title.
A plugin would also do the trick.

I looked around, but i couldn't find anyone who talked about this.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: for SEO purposes, I would recommend putting the full title in the URL, or at least the first few words. Search engines often place a priority on what is in the URL

Comment: Believe it or not, the url is actually humanly understandable as well. We have analysis of pages of a book, so the book is the category and the first 3 characters are the page number. Since the titles are a bit gimmicky to provoke curiosity, they often don't add to SEO.